# How to find type signatures of multiple imported methods in GHCI

Tags: haskell, types, ghci

I'm using a library, which I've loaded into GHCI.

From the names of the functions is not obvious to me which one I should be using; I'm sure it exists, and want to see a list of type signatures of the functions available to me.  I don't know how to do this.

- I can get a list of all the functions exported by the library by typing the module name and using tab-completing in GHCI.
- [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) is useless to me, because the library in question isn't covered.  Hoogle-style of searching would be useful, though.
- I know of GHCI's `:t`, but it only seems to work for a single function, and I don't want to do this for every single function that is being exported by the library.
- Running `grep -R :: ./*` or similar over the source directory may omit functions without explicit type signatures.
- The library has Haddock documentation, but it has around 1000 functions spread out amongst dozens of submodules, and it's tedious and error prone to manually search them all.

I'm open to try any method, but obviously prefer what's simple, portable, and repeatable.

Is there a way to find the type signatures of all exported functions in a library?  Or to find out which functions have a type signature that includes a certain type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just use `:browse Module.Name` and you'll see all the values exported by the module:

```
> :browse Data.Tagged
newtype Tagged s b = Tagged {unTagged :: b}
asTaggedTypeOf :: s -> Tagged s b -> s
retag :: Tagged s b -> Tagged t b
tagSelf :: a -> Tagged a a
untag :: Tagged s b -> b
untagSelf :: Tagged a a -> a
```